# Saving variables to table from service in Rails- attr_accessor issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, attr-accessor

### Short description

I need to save a field to a table. I used to do this from the controller and it worked perfectly, but now I need to set this field from the service instead. I am using attr_accessor but am not able to get it to work properly.

### Long description

I wrote a service (ToolService) that uses an api to create an array of hashes. I have previously saved this array to the object via the controller.

Controller:

```
1: class ToolsController < ApplicationController
2:  def create
3:   tool_hash = params.delete('tool')
4:   @tool = Tool.new
5:   # blah blah get params
6:   t = ToolService.new(# pass params to initialize service)
7:   @tool.all_data = t.run_tool_report(# pass params to get result)
8:  end
9: end
```

Service:

```
class ToolService
attr_accessor :all_data
 def initialize(# params)
  # initializing stuff
 end
 def run_tool_report(# params, including array_of_tools)
  @all_data = Array.new # create an array to hold all hashes of data
  array_of_tools.each do |each tool| 
   # run all api queries
   @each_tool_data = # hash of query results
   @all_data << @each_tool_data # add each hash of results to array 
  end
 return @all_data
 end
end
```

This works as expected. However, I need to implement [Delayed Jobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) because this query takes a long time. So, in the controller I have changed line 7 to `t.delay.run_tool_report(# pass params to get result)`. I thought that including `attr_accessor :all_data` in the service would allow the service write to the @tool.all_data field in the table, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

When I use `@tool.delay.all_data = t.run_tool_report(# pass params to get result)`, @tool.all_data is set to the id of the delayed job, not the array of results.

So, am I using attr_accessor incorrectly? Or is there some other way to set this field in the table?

Answer (score 1):

Delayed job comes in handy when you want to run task asynchronously. When you write `t.delay.run_tool_report` it creates an entry in the `delayed_jobs` model to be run in the background. This object is returned to you in the `@tool.all_data`. If you want the result of the `run_tool_report`, you need to run without `delay` and optimise your queries. `Preloading/eagerloading` and `caching` techniques might come handy.

Comment: Hmm, it's a very long query against the api and the data needs to be as recent as possible. I don't know if preloading/eagerloading or caching might be applicable.